# Can't add images on MAAS cloud

Tags: cloud, maas

I have been following this guide:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Deploying_Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_Juju

Everything goes well until almost end of guide is part:
EC2 API

To begin using the EC2 API, select Settings-> EC2 Credentials -> Download EC2 Credentials in the Openstack dashboard. Save the file (eg, /home/adam/openstack/"). We can then unzip these and begin using our cloud:

```
cd /home/adam/openstack
unzip 247e0c5de9dc415a8e411da643308eb6d-x509.zip
. ec2rc.sh
wget http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/server/server/releases/oneiric/beta-1/ubuntu-11.10-beta1-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz
uec-publish-tarball ./ubuntu-11.10-beta1-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz images
euca-add-keypair adam >adam.pk
euca-run-instances -k adam ami-00000002
```

Problem starts here: uec-publish-tarball ./ubuntu-11.10-beta1-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz images. I did found that it is cloud-publish-tarball, but even with that I get only this: Unable to run euca--describe-images.  Is environment for euca- set up?

So my question is how I can add images? I have used to creds, tried many different places / machines when doing this... but always same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem with your openstack setup (a credentials problem or even a problem with the installation itself).

As suggested in https://answers.launchpad.net/nova/+question/179016, I advise you to have a look in the log files in /var/lib/nova/ to try to gather more information about where the problem is exactly.